# Getting active contracts by date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling a little bit with detecting active contracts in a pandas DataFrame:
Suppose each row is a negotiation, and for each row I have two columns: initial_date and end_date.
What I want to know are the number of active contracts by date. I have done a VERY inefficient way so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

contracts = {'contract': {0: '0001-16',
  1: '0001-19',
  2: '0001-20',
  3: '0002-16',
  4: '0002-20'},
 'initial_date': {0: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2016-01-11 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2016-01-09 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')},
 'end_date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-12 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-12 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-06 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-12 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-12 00:00:00')}}

### making it a pandas dataframe
contracts= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(contracts)
### getting every date in dataframe
all_dates = pd.date_range(start = min(contracts['initial_date']), end=max(contracts['end_date']))

###getting active_contracts by all_date
active_contracts = []
for date in all_dates:
    active = 0
    for i in range(contracts.shape[0]):
        if contracts.iloc[i]['initial_date'] <=date <= contracts.iloc[i]['end_date']:
            active+=1
    active_contracts.append(active)

### plotting
plt.plot(all_dates,active_contracts)
plt.ylabel('Active Contracts')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot of active_contracts by all_dates after processing:
[image: Active contracts by date]
So, what makes me come here is the unefficiency of this and it seems to me that there must be a more pythonic way of doing so.

Comment: Hey Ricardo, welcome to stackoverflow, to enable the community to help you, you need to provide a sample input and output of your dataframe, a simple 5 rows of each would do. see [ask] and [mcve] this avoids ambiguity and time waste on both ends. I've given you a downvote, but will gladly remove when you've edited your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Manakin for your help. I've added the information to the question. Hope it is understandable now!

Comment: to make a question truly replicate, it needs to be as text, i.e all I would need to do is copy your text into my IDE and replicate your datasets and issue, we still also need what your expected output is. Remember we know nothing of your dataset. you can `print(df.head(10).to_dict()` and paste the input dataframe into your question.

Comment: Think I got it right this time! lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), (`[:, None]`), to compare each date with all rows in contracts to check if the date is inbetween, then sum the number of contracts where this is `True`.

First create a DataFrame of your dates then we do the comparison.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2021-01-01', freq='D')})

df['active'] = ((df['date'].to_numpy() >= contracts['initial_date'].to_numpy()[:, None])
                 & (df['date'].to_numpy() <= contracts['end_date'].to_numpy()[:, None])).sum(axis=0)
```

---

**Verification**

```
df.set_index('date').plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! tested this solution in a bigger dataframe and it performed really well! Marking this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'contract': ['24-02-2017', '24-02-1995'],'initial_date': ['24-02-2015', '25-02-2015'], 'end_date': ['24-02-2081', '24-02-2016']}
contracts = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
contracts
```

[image]

---

```
mask = (contracts['initial_date'] < contracts['contract']) & (contracts['end_date'] >= contracts['contract'])

contracts.loc[mask]
```

[image]

Comment: Thats not it.. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear in my question but IMO I was pretty clear. counting active 'rows' by date is not masking by today's date

Comment: the assumption was - that active contracts is between start and end.

Comment: What is the condition to classify contract as active?

Comment: Yes! your're right! but I'm evaluating per date, not by today. It's like i'm doing that mask for every date since the first contract until the last contract.. I think that's actually faster than my code lol. Will do some tests right now

Comment: @RicardoSampaio i edited question - now it's works not on now, but on contract date.

Comment: I see.. Still isn't what i'm looking for! I'm sorry, but i think I wasn't clear after all. I've updated the question with a full working example now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(nlog(n)) solution while the accepted answer is O(n*M). You only need to evaluate during starts and ends of the contracts. Starts add a contract and ends subtract one. You can further optimize it by using numpy cumulative sum function

```
def act_count(schedule):
    starts = schedule[["initial_date"]].rename(columns={"initial_date": "date"})
    starts["count"] = 1
    ends = schedule[["end_date"]].rename(columns={"end_date": "date"})
    ends["count"] = -1
    start_ends = pd.concat([starts, ends], ignore_index=True)
    start_ends.sort_values("date", inplace=True)
    start_ends = start_ends.groupby("date", as_index=False).sum()
    cur = 0 
    res = []
    for date, end_count in start_ends.values:
        #append previous value to get a "ladder" style chart
        res.append([date, cur])
        cur += end_count
        res.append([date, cur])
    return res

counts = act_count(contracts)

dates, counts = zip(*counts)
### plotting
plt.plot(dates, counts)

plt.ylabel("Active Contracts")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is really good! My mind was thinking this way but I just couldn't write it into code lol...   I will test this answer out as well and see how it performs! Thank you for your contribution